Connected Berkovich affinoid space with unique Shilov boundary
Let $X$ be a smooth connected affinoid space over a (algebraic closed, spherically complete) nonarchimedean field $K$, and $X’$ be an affinoid subspace contained in the interior of $X$, with Shilov boundary consisting of a unique point. I want to know if for all sufficiently small neighborhood $Y\subset X$ of $X’$, $Y$ also admits a one point Shilov boundary.
I think if $X$ is the Berkovich affine line and $X’$ is any affinoid subdomain with one point Shilov boudary, then $X’$ should be isomorphic to a disc so the above holds.
In general case, I want to know any counterexample, or if it might be true after putting more conditions (maybe strong ones) on $X$ or $K$.

This is not true. If $X$ is the Berkovich affine line with coordinate $T$ (or a disc with big radius if you really want it to be affinoid), you can choose $X'$ to be the flat annulus $\{|T|=1\}$. Any small enough neighborhood will be contained in an annulus of the form $\{r \le |T|\le s\}$, with $0 < r < 1 <s$, and its Shilov boundary will contain several points.

Thank you very much. You are right.
